# How to use ConfidentialClientApplication to perform AppOnly requests to Graph (Group.ReadWrite.All)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I've been playing with MSAL `Microsoft.Identity.Client.ConfidentialClientApplication` to perform app-only Microsoft Graph - Groups operations.

```cs
var RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
var clientApplication = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), null);
```

I'm stuck at the next step:

```cs
authenticationResult = clientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new string[]{"Group.ReadWrite.All"}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I get error `failed_to_acquire_token_silently`.

```cs
authenticationResult = clientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[]{"Group.ReadWrite.All"}, string.Empty).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I get error `invalid_scope`.

Not sure which direction I should continue.

Notes:

- With `PublicClientApplication` the same code works fine
- The app has both AppOnly `Group.ReadWrite.All` and Delegate `Group.ReadWrite.All` permissions
- With `PublicClienApplication` there's an unwanted UI dialog...

```cs
var clientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId);
authenticationResult = clientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to get the access token with the "group.readwrite.all" scope without a consent screen? (the 'unwanted ui dialog')?

Comment: I want to get access token via an unattended script with only clientid/clientsecret.

the 'unwanted ui dialog' via PublicClientApplication stops that flow.

Comment: Did you first consent to the app you are trying to use? No matter what kind of app you create, you will need to have a user consent to the app the first time it is being used so that consent is recorded. After that, you should be able to make subsequent calls without a user present. If you need more instructions here let me know and I will write an 'answer' for you.

Comment: I tried the steps again: register new app, create client secret, create mobile based redirecturl.  add App-Only Group.ReadWrite.All 

change ConfidentialClientApplication to use new clientid/secret - says failed_to_acquire_token_silently.
call PublicClientApplication with new clientid - UI ask to authenticate with admin user, asked to grant permissions (including Group.ReadWrite.All) - returns good token and can use this with graph.
call again with ConfidentialClientApplication and it says failed_to_aquire_token_silently again.

Answer (score 1):

Please try consenting to the Confident Client you created.
You can do this by modifying the following URL with your settings:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantID>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<AppID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<RedirectURI>&resource=<ResourceURI>&prompt=admin_consent
```

Make sure the information you put into that URL is the confidential client.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been gone 5 days, taking a second stab at this problem.  I don't think there's a way to add the prompt=admin_consent with either PublicClientApplication or ConfidentialClientApplication libraries is that correct?  I see several ADAL examples that tries to do this - but I was thinking MSAL was going to be able to do everything.
Is there a ConfidentialClientApplication example that shows how to do the basics?

Comment: I think you might be right in that ADAL doesn't support "admin_consent" specifically: [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.promptbehavior.aspx). Either way, you do not need ADAL to be the one that generates the URL for you. You can generate the URL yourself using the template I provided above. Note that ADAL doesn't do anything magical in the authentication steps, its just https calls to the various OAuth endpoints as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

Comment: I've made some progress with using ADAL to call the url and got through admin_consent.  I also got auth tokens.

I then switch to my MSAL ConfidentialClientApplication and using the same ClientID/ClientSecret I still get failed_to_acquire_token_silently.

I suspect I'm just confusing something basic about how to set up ConfidentialClientApplication.

Comment: How are you creating your application? To my knowledge, MSAL should only work with V2 applications, and ADAL only works with V1 apps, or something like that. Is it possible you are using the wrong client library for the wrong Application Type?

Comment: hmm I'm pretty much doing this.  https://aadguide.azurewebsites.net/integration/registerappv2/

Comment: It looks like the admin consent approach is different for V2 apps. See: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds). Rather than prompt=admin_consent, there's a different endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent. That page details the flow.